# Где будет создаваться архив?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть класс который создает архив, но я не пойму где этот архив сохраняется?

```
public class ZipClass {

private static final int BUFFER = 80000;
public static void zip(Map<Image, String> metadata, String zipFileName) {

    System.out.println("HERE WE GOT SIZE OF META IT IS : " +
            Metadata.getInstance().getMetadataMap().size());

    ZipOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName)));
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

        Iterator<Map.Entry<Image, String>> iterator = metadata.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Image, String> tmp = iterator.next();
//                Image image = tmp.getKey();
            String description = tmp.getValue();
            add(out, data, description);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если zipFileName просто название архива, то судя по всему в корне

Comment: укажите явное местоположение файла. например **/storage/emulated/0/** или использовать **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()**

Comment: а как указать путь? Я так понял, что если мы хотим сохранять на CD то нужно вместо имени написать так Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(); верно?

Comment: **String zipFileLocation=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+zipFileName;**

Answer (score 3):

Если zipFileName содержит только имя файла, то файл **скорее всего** сохранится туда, куда указывает метод контекста `getFilesDir()`. Обычно это data/data/xxx/files где xxx идентификатор приложения. **Однако для предсказуемости кода лучше всегда указывать явный путь до сохраняемых файлов**.

Каталог data/data приватный и читать оттуда может либо root (все подкаталоги) либо приложение - только свой каталог. Поэтому если открыть его без рутовых прав из того же es explorer - то он будет выглядеть пустым.

Путь до внутреннего каталога приложения можно получить с помощью `getFilesDir()`. Никаких дополнительных прав на чтение и запись из этого каталога не требуется.

Если требуется записать файл, который потом может прочитать другое приложение, то к имени файла надо добавлять путь. Путь публичного каталога можно получить следующим образом:

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null) - корневой каталог
context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) - картинки
context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) - закачки
```

и так далее согласно константам из Environment. При первом создании файлов в этих каталогах может возникнуть ошибка поскольку они скорее всего не существуют. Чтобы избежать ошибки надо перестраховываться и перед созданием файла вызывать 
mkdirs():

```
File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
if (dir != null) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

Получить путь до готового каталога и с его помощью сконструировать полный путь до файла можно так:

```
String path = dir.getAbsolutePath();
String filePath = path + File.pathSeparator + "archive.7z";
```

Для доступа на чтение/запись в публичных каталогам приложению требуются права `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Право WRITE включает в себя и READ.

Comment: Это только если создавать файлы с помошью метода http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: А как создать не файл а папку?

Comment: "Если zipFileName содержит только имя файла, то файл сохранится туда, куда указывает метод контекста getFilesDir()." -- можно подтвердить ссылкой на источник информации?

Comment: Ссылки нет. Говорю исходя из практических результатов (проверял 4.1, 5.1)

Comment: Опыт это хорошо, но если это не задокументировано, то поведение в любой версии может измениться. Автору ничего не мешает вызывать `getFilesDir()` когда надо, и все будет явно и предсказуемо.

Comment: Так я нигде и не говорил, что это правильно. Человек задал вопрос где окажется файл - судя по всему из-за приватности он файл найти там не смог. Правильно же всегда указывать путь до файла, понимать куда его система запишет и какие последствия от этого будут. Тот же getExternalFilesDir() не всегда выдается - каталог  может быть банально не смонтирован. Но да. Ответ поправлю :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! только у меня почему то при создании dir говорит, что результат будет проигнорирован вот я сделал скриншот https://dropmefiles.com/MjFXy  , не понятно создаст в итоге папку или нет?

Comment: Это означает, что результат выдаваемый методом mkdirs() будет проигнорирован потому что метод вызывается без присваивания. Это предупреждение компилятора, которое в общем в данном случае малополезно поскольку в первый раз при создании каталога(ов) он вернет true а затем будет возвращать false. Каталог если есть права доступа и путь правильный создастся.

Answer (score 0):

Туда, куда указывает этот параметр статического метода `String zipFileName`.

Comment: А что будет если я второй файл попробую записать по этому же пути?

Comment: Все как обычно, если имена файлов совпадают, новый перезаписывает предыдущий.